# Exception loading data with CursorLoader after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I'm having a strange issue with my application running on a Nexus 7 tablet.
I have two fragments that load data with CursorLoader from my custom ContentProvider.

When i startup the application it runs fine both in landscape and portait mode, loaders load data properly. The problem occurs when i rotate the screen: my Activity and both Fragments are correctly recreated and loaders are started again, as expected. They load data (debugging i saw that onLoadFinished is called for both loaders) but after that the application is FC with this exception:

```
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #4
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1094)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:354)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(Unknown Source)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-30 13:10:03.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14964):    ... 4 more
```

Honestly, stacktrace doesn't help because it doesn't contains any reference to my code and also it's a pretty strange issue because, as a said above, both fragments work the first time i launch the application, work properly on the phone layout but crash on my tablet layout after screen rotation.

EDIT:

In both fragments i load data in the method onActivityCreated method simply calling getLoaderManager.initLoader(....);

This is how i created my loaders:

First fragment

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MyContract.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    return cursorLoader;
}
```

second fragment:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MyContract.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
}
```

This is the declaration of my CP's content uri:

```
//MyContract class
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + MyProvider.AUTHORITY + "/items");

//In MyProvider class
public static final String AUTHORITY = "it.rciovati.mypackage.MyProvider"
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are doing cursor loading. It looks like this has to do with uri which you are using does not have a scheme associated with it

Comment: What doesn't this exactly means? I thought that maybe there is an error with my content provider implementation but i can't understand why the first time i launch the application it works.

Comment: I meant the crash. Anyway i think the uri you are passing to the loader does not have : (colon) anywhere in the string . That is why it is crashing. Print all uris that you have and check

Comment: I wrote above how i've declared my content uri.

Comment: the problem is not with the Content uri in your ContentProvider, its in the app where you are laoding the uri. Post the code where you are creating the uri to load

Comment: I added the code when i created the loader, as you can see i query directly the content uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
In my layout i have a third fragment that loads other data and there was a wrong check on it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @MattWear basically due to a wrong check I was passing null to the Uri parameter.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in `android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider()` that was only fixed in November of 2013. The details of that bug can be seen here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=904551

Essentially the function could not handle if the Uri is null and would cause a crash. In order to properly support older Android versions you'll need to either ensure you never pass in a null Uri, or catch the NPE that is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem. Turns out it's a really easy bug to squash. Example based on my code

```
        Uri content_uri = null;

        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("ID_BUNDLE_KEY")) {
            int word_id_to_query = bundle.getInt(ID_BUNDLE_KEY, 1);
            content_uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(WordListContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, word_id_to_query);

        }

        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), content_uri,
                projections, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARGS, null);
```

My mistake was to use "ID_BUNDLE_KEY" as the argument rather than ID_BUNDLE_KEY. The latter being already a final static String variable. Thus bundle.containsKey will always return false. This led to the variable of content_uri containing "null" when passed into the new CurorLoader function. My advice is to verify in your own code that a "null" uri is NOT erringly passed in.

For extra info, line 1094 of the ContentResolver.java in Android 4.1.2 AOSP code is really when the condition of [uri.getscheme() != "content"] returns false, leading to a null provider. It's this null provider that the runtime library is complaining about.